# WhatsApp Web doesn't work on the phone

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When i try to start WhatsApp Web on the phone, the QR-Code scanner screen does not even open, but i get a passive notification "check your internet connection on the phone". 
While i can chat with WhatsApp without any problems, so the internet connection and the connection to WhatsApp cannot be the real problem.

How can i get Whatsapp to recognize that the internet connection is fine and open the qr code scanner?

Comment: I would re-install the app and see if that works. That is not a normal thing that happens in the app. Also, reboot your phone and try it again.

Comment: Also, if you're worried about backing up your chats, you can take a back-up on Drive, and restore that back-up. Try un-installing the app as Devin Ersnoy pointed out.

Comment: I try to avoid services like google drive and so on, that's why i am a bit hesitant. On the other hand its quite possible that something is broken because i restored the data by copying the WhatsApp folder and restoring a TitaniumBackup on a new phone. Maybe i try how good the backup in the WhatsApp folder can be restored, iirc this should be possible as well.

Comment: Did you tried ON/OFF your Wi-Fi or Mobile internet connection? After reading your post I tried with my Wi-Fi OFF/ON, and QR Code screen was opened by WhatsApp. When there was no internet WhatsApp throw error saying `You don't have any network access now` which is different error then what you wrote in your Question. You may upgrade WhatsApp to latest version and try!

Comment: I tried several on/off settings of mobile data and wifi and whatsapp should be the latest version (a few updates since the post). I suspect some problems with xprivacy/androidfirewall, but it worked on the old device with the same rules. And general network access works as well. I think i do a backup+reinstall when i have enough time to make good backups to make sure i can roll back when i lose any chats during testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after a Backup & Reset:

- Make a new local backup (via settings -> chats -> chat-backup)
- uninstall WhatsApp
- install WhatsApp
- Login via Phone number and sms verification (even when there's a backup)
- Whatsapp finds the local backup and asks if you want to import it. Nothing is lost, but a few settings. Profile image is restored, but for the screen name whatsapp asks you again (and suggests the name from your google account)

So if someone has the same problem: backup & restore works fine.
Of course it doesn't hurt to have a TitaniumBackup, adb backup or similiar as well.